# Displaying live ticker data in iOS app

Tags: ios, rest, tableview

I am consuming data from a REST Web Service via RestKit and would like to display it in a tableview. Consuming the data works really good. Now I want to display the data in a table. The web service is requested every two seconds.

How would you implement the tableview? How to get to know changes? Is there some mechanism in iOS that helps to get the delta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no mechanism that helps you out. But you can consume the data on another thread (in the background) and "append" the rows to the TableView, dont use reload than your tableview isn't useable.

1. Load up your tableview with data.
2. Start an process in the background wich calls your webservice every 2 seconds.
3. Create an observer and send an notification when the call is done.
4. And than append the rows (with animation for example) to the tableview.

I hope that helps you out a bit =]